# Call function with arguments in -ScriptBlock of Invoke-Command Powershell command

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I have two server one of them is Active directory and other is Windows10.
I want to write a Powershell script that delete and make a directory.(for easy situation I choose delete and make directory but in real, The script used for getting group and organization unit of active directory.)

I write three function and below Powershell script. the first one is for run command on remote server and two of them for create and delete a directory. The my_powershell_script.ps1

```
Param($choosen_function, $username, $password, $remote_address, $absolute_path)
function run_commend_on_remote_server {
    param ($choosen_function, $username, $password, $remote_address)
    $secpsw = $password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
    $credobject = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $UserName, $secpsw
    $psrs = New-PSSession -Credential $credobject -ComputerName  $remote_address
    Enter-PSSession $psrs
    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {$choosen_function -absolute_path $absolute_path} -Session $psrs
    Exit-PSSession
    Remove-PSSession $psrs
}

function delete_directory{
    param($absolute_path) 
    Remove-Item $absolute_path -Recurse
}

function make_directory{
    param($absolute_path) 
    mkdir $absolute_path
}

run_commend_on_remote_server -choosen_function $choosen_function -username $username -password $password -remote_address $remote_address -absolute_path $absolute_path
```

When I run this script as below I got errors:

```
my_powershell_script.ps1 -choosen_function make_directory -username admin -password admin -remote_address 192.168.2.22
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: The errors is:
At C:\mohammad.ps1:8 char:52
+     Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {$choosen_function -absolute_path $ab ...
+                                                    ~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '-absolute' in expression or statement.
At C:\mohammad.ps1:8 char:61
+ ... Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {$choosen_function -absolute_path $absolu ...
+                                                             ~~~~~
Unexpected token '_path' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things which need to be changed in order for this script to work.

1. On your `run_commend_on_remote_server` function, you're using `Enter-PSSession` which is meant for interactive sessions, and then you're using `Invoke-Command`, in this case if I understand your intent correctly `Enter-PSSession` **has to be removed**.
2. On the same function, inside `Invoke-Command` script blocks's, `$choosen_function` is being used however the 2 helper functions have not been defined on that scope ([remote scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables?view=powershell-7.2#using-local-variables)). You need to pass the definition of your functions if you want to use them remotely. Same thing applies for `$absolute_path`. In order to pass locally defined variables into the remote scope, you can use either `-ArgumentList` or `$using:`, see [Example 9](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.2#example-9--include-local-variables-in-a-command-run-on-a-remote-computer) from the `Invoke-Command` Doc.

> The command uses the `Using` scope modifier to identify a local variable in a remote command. By default, all variables are assumed to be defined in the remote session. The `Using` scope modifier was introduced in PowerShell 3.0.

3. Since the **name** of the helper function you want to run is stored in a variable, in order to *execute it*, you would need to use the [call operator `&`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#call-operator-) or the [dot sourcing operator `.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#dot-sourcing-operator-) to invoke it, i.e.: **`& $choosen_function`**.
4. Instead of passing `UserName` and `Password` as argument of your script, I would personally recommend you to call [`Get-Credential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-credential?view=powershell-7.2) inside your script.
5. **`-absolute_path`** is being used as parameter for `run_commend_on_remote_server` but the function does not have such parameter.

With these points being understood, here is how you could approach your script:

```
[cmdletbinding()]
param(
    [ValidateSet('delete_directory', 'make_directory')]
    $choosen_function,
    $remote_address,
    $absolute_path
)

function delete_directory{
    # code here    
}

function make_directory{
    # code here
}

# store both function's definition, this will be used
# to pass them to the remote scope
$def = @(
    ${function:delete_directory}.ToString()
    ${function:make_directory}.ToString()
)

function run_commend_on_remote_server {
    param ($choosen_function, $remote_address, $Credential, $absolute_path)

    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
        # bring the definition of both functions to this scope
        $deldir, $makedir = $using:def
        # define both functions
        ${function:delete_directory} = $deldir
        ${function:make_directory} = $makedir

        # invoke the chosen function
        & $using:choosen_function -absolute_path $using:absolute_path
    } -Credential $Credential -ComputerName $remote_address
}

# Here we call Get-Credential to get the pop-up for username and secure password
$cred = Get-Credential

$params = @{
    choosen_function = $choosen_function
    credential       = $cred
    remote_address   = $remote_address
    absolute_path    = $absolute_path
}
run_commend_on_remote_server @params
```